# DATE_CHANGED Broadcast is not being fired

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have one `DATE_CHANGED BroadcastReciever` in my application but it seems its not firing up at mid night instead its firing my myreciever at 12.00 day time.

i have declare this in manifest file as

```
  <receiver android:name=".DateChangedReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and my DateChangedReceiver.java file is like

```
   public class DateChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED)){
            //my task...
        }
    }

}
```

any idea why is this happening. Help Guys.

Comment: You probably should use the AlarmManager for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED fires when user manually **changes date from settings** of phone not for change of day.
I have faced that problem and finally use AlarmManager.