# Handling client's false date changes

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

In my android application (android is not important, any client side application is similar) I run a service regularly. When some time elapsed (for example 7 days) and user doesn't make a goal I send a notification. But if user changes phone's time to a future date (which makes false positive) I send notification. But it is false.

```
long differenceMinutes = 
     Math.abs( (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L) - lastGoalTime) / 60;
```

Good path:
- User made a goal at 15 June 2014 and I saved this date to device.
- My service checks for new goals.
- On 22 June 2014, if no new goal wasn't completed I send notification.

Bad path:
- User made a goal at 15 June 2014 and I saved this date to device.
- On 16 June 2014 user changes his local time to 22 June 2014.
- My service checks for new goals.
- No new goal completed, although only 1 day passed, application send notification.
- I don't want application to send notification until 7 days completed.

How can I come through this type of situation ?
I don't prefer to connect a time server and get current time.
Is there a workaround for this type of problems ?
I'm sorry if I'm not aware of the terminology.

Comment: If you can't trust the system, you have to rely on a system you can trust.  You can't count the milliseconds yourself and have them be reliable as all hardware owned by users has errors in counting, which is why they use timeservers to correct.

Comment: This might be impossible to solve without relying on SOME external resource.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround or maybe even a solution could be detecting the DATE_CHANGED event & updating the server?

Extend a broadcast receiver, and add the following action to the intent filter, and of course it can be done through xml.

```
intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED");
```

Comment: When is that fired?  Every new day?  Or *only* when the user changes the system date?

Comment: Oh, and interestingly enough, there's a [bug filed on this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2880) -- not saying you *should* have known about that, just an FYI.  I didn't even know about this event until your post!

Comment: this is fired when users change the date through the settings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831789/date-changed-broadcast-is-not-being-fired